# Tensorflow evaluate network with different batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a trained network with input:

```
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, width, height, channels), name='input')
```

In practice, I want to be able to make predictions with variable *batch_size* (with maximum batch size *batch_max*, say 100), i.e.,

```
imgs = get_batch(batch_size=1)
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs})
imgs = get_batch(batch_size=100)
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs})
```

Now I observed the following behaviour:

```
imgs_batch1 = get_batch(batch_size=1)
imgs_batch100 = get_batch(batch_size=100)
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs_batch1})
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs_batch100}) # takes 1.5s
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs_batch100}) # takes 1.0s
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs_batch1})
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs_batch100}) # takes 1.5s
session.run([output], feed_dict={'input:0': imgs_batch100}) # takes 1.0s
```

Otherwise said, changing the batch size slows down the evaluation. The first evaluation of a batch size is significantly slower than direct following evaluations of same batch size.

That sounds reasonable I can find logical reasons why that would be the case. But given that I know the maximum batch size that will ever be sent as input, is there not a smarter way to achieve this without the slowing down as soon as there is a batch of size 1 being sent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pad your batches, i.e creating an example full of 0 and put it multiple time inside your batch if your batch is less than your max_size. When you have the results just discard those coming from the dummy example.

Comment: But then I suppose I would not have gain times when running batch size 1 right? Since it would essentially be a batch size of max_size with (max_size - 1) dummies?

Comment: Yes you are right. But it if you have many time batches of size 100 , and few batch of 1 , maybe there will be a gain of a speed. Otherwise no.

Comment: Can this problem be solved with queues or things like that?